# Dynamic memory allocation of array in C & C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

Look at the user input in C and C++ code (inside for loop).We use *(p+i) in user input in C++ and (p+i) in C. Whats the reason for missing * in C?
Plz explain! Take a look at the COMMENT line... inside for loop

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int n,i;
  cout << "Ent size" << endl;
  cin>>n;
  int *p = new int [n];
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>*(p+i);//LOOK AT THIS LINE
  cout<<"------------\n\n";
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    cout<<*(p+i)<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  int n;
  printf("Ent size!\n");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  int *p=(int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%d",(p+i));//LOOK AT THIS LINE

  printf("-------\n\n");
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%d\n",(p+i));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect them to be the same???? `scanf` and `std::cin` are not the same thing.

Comment: And in Python you write `array[i] = input()` (yes, that is not exactly the same). So what is the point? Different languages have different ways to accomplish a certain task.

Comment: If you wrote those array accesses like a sane person the C++ would be `cin >> p[i];` and the C would be `scanf("%d", &p[i]);`. The C++ code expects an object and the C function expects an address.

Comment: Hello I have an apple and an orange but they are not the same colour why is this???

Answer (score 5):

The difference exists due to the existence of references in C++.
 In C++ `operator >>` for objects of type int is declared the following way

```
basic_istream<charT,traits>& operator>>(int& n);
```

As you see the parameter of the operator has type `int &`. It means that the argument is passed to the function by reference that is the function deals directly with the argument not with its copy.

So this statement

```
cin>>*(p+i);
```

is equivalent to

```
cin.operator( *( p + i ) );
```

and the compiler does not creates a copy of the object specified by the expression `*( p + i )`. It uses the object itself because the object is passed by reference.

In C in fact there is also used a reference to the argument but it is specified as a pointer because the notion of references is not defined in C.

When somebody says that an object is passed by reference to a function in C it means that the object is passed indirectly using a pointer to the object.
In C++ it means that there is used the notion of the reference.

So if you want that function `scanf` would store the input data in the object itself you have to pass it indirectly to the function by using a pointer to the object.

```
scanf("%d",(p+i));
```

Here `p + i` is a pointer to object `*( p + i )`.

Consider these two simple programs

**C++**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x = 10;
    int &rx = x;

    std::cout << "x = " << std::endl;

    rx = 20;

    std::cout << "x = " << std::endl;
}
```

The same in C can be written the following way using a pointer because C does not have the notion of references

**C**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int x = 10;
    int *rx = &x;

    printf( "x = %d\n", x );

    *rx = 20;

    printf( "x = %d\n", x );
}
```